# SQL to get whole words till end from the keyword

Tags: sql, sql-server

Consider I have text from the field (notes) as below:

```
Please check http://example.com
```

I want a SQL query which fetches the link part only. That is to find keyword http and print till the last.

Output:

```
http://example.com
```

Also if the text field doesnt have any link, can we print NA?

```
CASE WHEN sys like '%Clo%'
THEN RIGHT( i.notes,LEN(i.notes) - CHARINDEX('http',i.notes,1)+1) 
ELSE "No Link Available" END  AS Cl_Link
```

Comment: Which _version_ of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, etc.)?

Comment: SQL server for now

Comment: So what have you tried and where did you get stuck?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SQL Server you can consider this below logic-

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Please check http://example.com'
SELECT RIGHT(@T,LEN(@T) - CHARINDEX('http:',@T,1)+1)
```

For MySQL-

```
SET @T = 'Please check http://example.com';  
SELECT RIGHT(@T,LENGTH(@T) - POSITION("http:" IN @T)+1)
```

In case of select query using table, queries will be-

```
-- SQL Server
SELECT RIGHT(column_name,LEN(column_name) - CHARINDEX('http:',column_name,1)+1) FROM your_table_name

-- MySQL
SELECT RIGHT(column_name,LENGTH(column_name) - POSITION("http:" IN column_name)+1) FROM your_table_name
```

To apply 'NA' when no link available, please use the below logic-

```
DECLARE @T VARCHAR(MAX) = 'Please check http://example.com'
SELECT 
CASE 
    WHEN CHARINDEX('http:',@T,1) >= 1 THEN RIGHT(@T,LEN(@T) - CHARINDEX('http:',@T,1)+1)
    ELSE 'NA'
END
```

Comment: can i have sql w/o declare statement?

Comment: @rose Just use this logic with your actual table.

Comment: If you are selecting values from a table, you can pass the column name directly in place of @T. Just ignore first line with DECLARE/SET from 2 sample query that case.

Comment: and for SQL server?

Comment: hii can i have else condiion to it? if the text doesnt have any link then print na

Comment: @rose please check the edited answer with new script below.

Comment: i recently got some issues witht he same. the first letter h gets disappeared from the value. any help?

Comment: I am checking.. Can you provide a sample string/url? @rose

Comment: had user access https://4rtei.trusted.com//servlet/ --> ttps://4rtei.trusted.com//servlet
one such example

Comment: Yes, this is because of http vs https :) i am checking how I can make necessary changes.

Comment: CASE when CHARINDEX('http',i.notes,1) >= 1 THEN RIGHT (i.notes,LEN(i.close_notes) - CHARINDEX('http',i.notes,1)+1)
    ELSE 'Link Not Available' END  AS Link

this is what i am using.. i t works fine for few but not for all:(

Comment: can you check this link - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=879cf899a6021ecda1c2675e3db21163

Comment: perfect. what was the issue before? ALso i need else condition saying link not available.Can you pls update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215302/discussion-between-mkrabbani-and-rose).

Answer (score 0):

Below is the query for your reference, executed on mysql:

```
SELECT substr(columnname,locate('http',columnname)) as link 
FROM `tablename` where column=value
```

Comment: Error type: Odbc error. Odbc operation attempted: SQLExecDirect. [HY000:195: on SQLHANDLE] [ODBC SQL Server Wire Protocol driver][Microsoft SQL Server]'locate' is not a recognized built-in function name

Answer (score -2):

For MySQL try this:

`select REGEXP_SUBSTR(text_column, 'http\:\/\/([\\w\\.\\S]+)') from mytest`

Comment: this question about SQL-SERVER tag, this answer not useful

Comment: Whoops, i missed that, just saw SQL in the title